# Need help with MySQL database (VB.NET)

Tags: mysql, database, date

I'm trying to create a system that can calculate money spend on monthly or a year. Now, roughly I have created 3 tables (actually there are 5 but 2 of them are items list and their prices so there is nothing wrong with it) on my database that is:-

(i) Daily - Field (Num, DTotal, Date)   >> save all item's value by day

(ii) Monthly - Field (Num, MTotal, StartDate) >> save all values from Daily table from a starting date  until the end of month of that date.

(iii) Year - Field (num, YTotal, StartDate)  >> save all values from Monthly table from a staring month until the end of the year.

The Daily part I have succeeded but the problem now is with the Monthly part. I don't know how to calculate it. How am I supposed to read the Daily table from a date until another date? Let's say I want to save from 15/8/2011 until 31/8/2011. Help please.

Comment: Tables ii) and iii) are redundant if you plan on using a database. Normally (in the DBMS sense of the word) you would have just table i) and write queries to get at monthly and yearly data. Read up on relational database design.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into monthly (ytotal, StartDate)
select sum(Dtotal), MONTH(Date) date
group by MONTH(Date)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

Also, make sure to put a unique index on Monthly.StartDate. That and the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause will protect you in case the insert is run several times.

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html